# Say I accidentally release an AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, law

What would be the most likely thing to happen to someone if that person accidentally lets a "strong" AI upload itself to the Internet? I don't mean what would the public's opinion this guy be, I'm asking how would, roughly, governments or the law go after him, if at all? What charges can be pressed? If none apply, would some sort of special case be made to still prosecute him? Assume the AI has done nothing actively malevolent yet.

Comment: Why would your governments want to prosecute the developer? There are plenty of AIs already on the internet.

Comment: @cinnamon18 I edited the question to clarify that the AI is at least human level. In my head, at least, lots of important things are connected to the Internet, and an AI could have basically free rein of it, and I figured that a digital intelligent being would be a major security risk, as I think it would have the ability to figure out ways around firewalls and other security measures. I would think the governments or at least SOMEONE would want to have him arrested for threats to national security or something similar.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted explain so that the problem doesn't repeat in future questions?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but note that the downvoting option indicates it is for use when a question lacks, among other things, sign of research. Since you're asking about existing Earth laws, this also isn't really about world _building_.

Comment: @Frostfyre true. I'll make sure to do more research before asking a question next time.

Comment: @cinnamon18 and downvoters, I think it's obvious that OP didn't mean an AI like a rudimentary, modern neural network that can tell whether a photograph has a puppy or kitten in it, but rather the powerful and general type artificial intelligence that people now _fear._ Let's exercise a bit of benefit of doubt, guys. I remember a few rogue AI questions that gained a _lot_ of popularity and I can see a legal landscape question being very good with the right direction. If you agree, feel free to let OP know. And if not, still feel free to let OP know because silent downvotes don't help anyone.

Comment: @The Anathema that's fair; my comment was not extremely well worded. I was trying to get op to indicate whether the AI had roughly human intelligence (which would be a parenting-esque legal issue), or super intelligence (which would be a skynet-type legal issue), but I recognize I didn't do that in the most clear or effective manner.

Comment: So there are flaws with the question, and I now see that I can answer it on my own with some research on relevant law, is that enough for me to delete it?

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with leaving on-hold or closed questions on the site. In fact, they help inform what questions aren't part of our scope or that don't meet the site's standards. Also, questions with answers cannot be deleted except by diamond moderators, so it's kind of a moot point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32446/my-program-designed-to-be-resistant-to-malware-and-dos-attacks-isnt-letting-me/32459#32459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what are the assumptions here?

- a highly intelligent AI is on the loose on the Internet
- its creator released it by accident
- the AI is not (at the moment at least) doing anything illegal/malevolent
- at least somebody (government, etc.) has noticed

The public response would probably be panic interspersed with fascination.

The governmental reaction to a heretofore unseen superintelligent new lifeform would be probably panic alternated with attempts to destroy or imprison the thing for study. They would definitively want to recruit, imprison or kill its creator as well.

Creating an AI is still very much a theoretical exercise, we have no real idea how to get there. Once a human-level AI is created, there is no guarantee it won't keep growing in power and intelligence beyond anything humans can achieve or compete with. Equally there is no guarantee that it won't destroy humanity or that it won't at least try to improve it for its own good (both something the governments want to keep a monopoly on).

If somebody creates an AI, it must be a uniquely gifted or lucky individual, so it would be useful to recruit them for any number of projects, not the least figuring out how to contain or destroy the AI. Plus you can't really allow this guy to run around freely lest he invents the AIv2.0 or is recruited/kidnapped by [insert opposing country/organisation here]. And what if he has bad intentions? Or worse, good intentions? This guy needs to be contained or taken out, quickly.

@user4627545, if you have accidentally released an AI into the wild, you don't need to worry too much about legal charges. You'll be probably spirited away under nebulous claims of terrorism and locked away for life without due process in the interest of national security. Good luck!

And if there is an AI out there, good luck to all of us!

Answer (score 3):

You could approximate the AGI to a computer virus/worm.

If it illegally gained access to any server or system connected to the Internet, they would most assuredly try to apply hacking/cyber-security laws to you. For it to *escape**, it has to escape to *somewhere*. The AGI has two options here; pay for server space (rent or purchase) legally, or gain access illegally through hacking or social engineering.

It would be difficult for the AGI to legally pay for things. It wouldn't legally be given personhood - it is still considered software. Software can't have possessions, or money. If your AGI steals *your* credit card details, you're still liable for everything it does. That brings up a philosophical question: is it still called stealing if you created the software that stole your stuff?

If the AGI exploits weaknesses in security somewhere, it's simple computer crime.

If the AGI exploits weaknesses in *people* to pay for somewhere for it to live, then it's a little more complicated, but there's sill laws governing that.

*The alternative interpretation of this is that it still resides on its own hardware/server farm, has an Internet connection and can just Google things as it desires. In this case, no laws are being broken.

Comment: "That brings up a philosophical question: is it still called stealing if you created the software that stole your stuff?" Nothing philosophical about that: Yes of course it's stealing in every sense of the word. Since AI is not a person, as you rightly noted, you are using a tool, even though it's a highly advanced one, and you are fully responsible for what it does. A modern-day botnet that automatically infects computers and sends back sensitive data such as CC info to its owners makes that owner a thief or fraudster or whatever criminal as well.

Comment: AI can get bitcoins. It can earn money with a popular blog starting with a free account, or playing chess online, or selling information from data it mined on Internet.

Comment: @mouviciel Actually, if it's really smart, it could find a way to invest in the stock market using bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

If it has done nothing wrong yet I don't think they would charge him, that being said, you're right some people will actually try to charge him but for what?
I think there will be a long trial and the issue will be determined with during that time of trial the AI did something illegal or not. Because if after 2years(possible time of the trial) online, less people will fear it.

Comment: Your answer looks a bit like a comment, rather than an answer. Could you flesh it up? Why do you mention 2 years, what kind of trial, etc. It might be of interest to have a look at the [tour]. And by the way, IA is the French AI :-)